# Обособление после противительного союза

Tags: пунктуация

"Тем не менее" обычно не выделяется запятыми. Нужно ли обособлять "тем не менее" в данном предложении: "Всё было глупым, нелепым, нелогичным, непоследовательным, но тем не менее оно свершилось…" Сомнения возникли, потому что интонации предполагают отсутствие плавности.

Comment: По мне, так полная плавность. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обособлять не нужно.

"Тем не менее" не может выступать вводным словосочетанием или наречием, которое можно обособляться по воле автора.
Согласно справочнику пунктуации, "тем не менее" может лишь быть частицей, не требующей обособления, или союзом на границе двух простых предложений — запятая ставится только перед союзом. После противительного союза — частица.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_731

Пример после противительного союза со справочника:
*Мюллер долго наблюдал за тем, как медленно, еле заметно, но тем не менее неуклонно лучи двигались по комнате.*